# If $F$ divides segment $EA$ such that $EF/FA=12/10$, can I say that $EF=12$ and $FA=10$?

Tags: geometry, fractions

[image: My question]

So I have a question in math. I'm not too sure if this is possible to say or not (or if it makes any sense). In the picture, I have line segment EA that can be broken down to EF and FA.

> I figured out the ratio for $EF/FA$ and it is $12/10$. My question is can I just say that $EF=12$ and $FA=10$, just like that?

Like, in my mind, I am thinking that you can do that because to find line segment $EA$, you need $EF/FA$ and it corresponds to $12/10$ and you could just take the top parts equaling each other ($EF=12$) and same as the bottom ($FA=10$)?

Comment: I think it's something that is simple that I might've forgotten if you can or can not do and if it equals each other or not.

Comment: You can't do that without further information because $EF=6$ and $FA=5$ would also satisfy $EF/FA=\dfrac{12}{10}=\dfrac{6}{5}$.

Comment: There are circumstances where you can decide on the "unit of length" in a convenient way like you are suggesting. But without knowing the context of this, we cannot say if it is one of those circumstances. Surely you have something more to be concerned about than just this three points. But what you can _certainly_ do is to pick a name of some variable that has not appeared anywhere else in the problem; suppose $x$ is such a variable, then you can say $EF = 12x$ and $FA = 10x$ where $x$ is a number to be determined later (or maybe never determined, depending on what you need).

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one dealing with the actual question in hand, rather than one that could be applied to billions of problems.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you all for helping !

Answer (score 1):

What you can say
is that there is a length
$v$ such that
$EF = 12v$
and
$FA = 10v$.